# Use parLapply in parallel in a loop R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I ran `parLapply` in a `parallel` in a loop in R, but I got an error:

```
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)
cl<-makeCluster(4) #change the 2 to your number of CPU cores
registerDoSNOW(cl)
foreach(1:2) %dopar% {
    clusterExport(cl, "parLapply")
    parLapply(cl, 1:2,function(exponent)2^exponent) 
}
```

when launching this code, I got the following error:

```
> Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'c1' not found"
```

Could anyone help me to explain why? Is it possible to use `parLapply` in `parallel` in a loop?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cluster objects can't be exported because they can't be safely serialized and sent to the workers since they contain socketConnection objects. Instead, you should create them on each of the workers as part of the worker initialization. Cluster creation can take significant time, so it can be important to create only one cluster object per worker regardless of the number of iterations in your foreach loop.

Here's an example that uses the `clusterEvalQ` function to initialize and clean up the workers so you can execute `parLapply` inside a foreach loop:

```
library(doSNOW)

# Start cluster on master and register it for use with doSNOW
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

# Start cluster on workers
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(parallel)
  cl <- makeCluster(2)
})

# Execute nested parallel loop
r <-
  foreach(1:2, .noexport='cl', .packages='parallel') %dopar% {
      parLapply(cl, 1:2, function(exponent)2^exponent)
  }

# Stop clusters on workers
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  stopCluster(cl)
})

# Stop cluster on master
stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the package list and use the below updated command. It is working for me. Plus you need to either define separate cluster *cl* within the worker node. Or you could try clusterCall function on cl to create a subprocess that again creates a cluster.

```
library(doParallel)
cl<-makeCluster(2,outfile = "")
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(1:2, .export = c('cl','parLapply') , .packages = 'doParallel' ) %dopar% {
  cl2<-makeCluster(2,outfile = "")
  registerDoParallel(cl2)
  parLapply(cl2, 1:2,function(exponent)2^exponent) 
  stopCluster(cl2)
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

In my opinion , nesting a parallel inside is only adding overhead to the process . It might be better to avoid such nesting.

Comment: Thanks! When I run your codes, there is no more the error, but the obtained results are "NULL". Do you know why?

Comment: It works when removing "stopCluster(cl2) ". However, without stopCluster, is there a problem?

Comment: stopCluster is a nice way of making sure that cluster initialisation is stopped. Else the cluster state would be up till the program exits. This would create overheads and is not recommended.

Comment: Your foreach loop is throwing away the return value from parLapply and returning the NULL returned by stopCluster. If you create a cluster in each iteration, you should also stop it, so you should save the return value from parLapply in a variable to return at the end of the foreach loop.